# Editing the data in last column

Tags: python, perl, bash, shell

I have a datafile (tab separated) which looks like this:

```
chr1    38045559    38046059    chr1:38045559-38046559_NM_001142726_C1orf122_+,chr1:38045559-38046559_NM_198446_C1orf122_+,chr1:38045952-38046952_NM_024640_YRDC_-
chr1    205291045   205291545   chr1:205290545-205291545_NM_018566_YOD1_-
chr1    1499717 1500625 chr1:1499625-1500625_NM_014188_SSU72_-
chr1    1679941 1680441 chr1:1679441-1680441_NM_001198995_NADK_-
chr1    1699769 1700657 chr1:1699269-1700269_NM_023018_NADK_-,chr1:1699657-1700657_NM_001198993_NADK_-
chr1    1701368 1701868 chr1:1700868-1701868_NM_001198994_NADK_-
chr1    1812386 1812886 chr1:1811886-1812886_NM_002074_GNB1_-
chr1    2066155 2066655 
chr1    2149493 2149993 chr1:2149493-2150493_NM_003036_SKI_+
chr1    2312573 2313353 chr1:2312353-2313353_NM_024848_MORN1_-,chr1:2312573-2313573_NM_007033_RER1_+
```

Where:

- the first three columns are the co-ordinates and
- the last column contains a set of zero or more annotation records

  - each annotation record is seperated by a comma
  - fields within the annotation record are seperated by an underscore or a colon

What I want is to get the first three columns as it is and the fifth field from each annotation record. for example for row 1 the output should be something like this

```
chr1    38045559    38046059   C1orf122
                               C1orf122
                               YRDC
```

What I have done, is I have already splited my data in last column based on comma ","

using `tr ',' '\t' <input>temp1`

Now what I have is a file which looks like this

```
chr1    38045559    38046059    chr1:38045559-38046559_NM_001142726_C1orf122_+  chr1:38045559-38046559_NM_198446_C1orf122_+ chr1:38045952-38046952_NM_024640_YRDC_-
chr1    205291045   205291545   chr1:205290545-205291545_NM_018566_YOD1_-
chr1    1499717 1500625 chr1:1499625-1500625_NM_014188_SSU72_-
chr1    1679941 1680441 chr1:1679441-1680441_NM_001198995_NADK_-
chr1    1699769 1700657 chr1:1699269-1700269_NM_023018_NADK_-   chr1:1699657-1700657_NM_001198993_NADK_-
chr1    1701368 1701868 chr1:1700868-1701868_NM_001198994_NADK_-
chr1    1812386 1812886 chr1:1811886-1812886_NM_002074_GNB1_-
chr1    2066155 2066655 
chr1    2149493 2149993 chr1:2149493-2150493_NM_003036_SKI_+
chr1    2312573 2313353 chr1:2312353-2313353_NM_024848_MORN1_-  chr1:2312573-2313573_NM_007033_RER1_+
```

Now, I need a bit of your expertise to get me to the desired output format.

Please guide me to get the desired output in  python/perl/shell.

Comment: What have you tried? Is the "annotation" simply the numbers and letters between underscores last in the line?

Comment: I already said it in question. I failed to go any further, and that was the reason I posted it here.

Comment: StackOverflow is not a code writing service. We help show you where your coding went wrong.

Comment: TLP with all respect, I need a guidance to get that format of output. you don't have to write a code for me and you neither have to be so sarcastic ;)

Comment: @ TLP: Down voting a question is a best way to answer?

Comment: I am not being sarcastic, I am stating a basic fact. Your question is valid, but it is not about coding, it is about having the code written for you. You should state it as a coding question in order to have it better received by the readers. No, I did not downvote you. Someone did that because of the things I told you.

Comment: @Angelo: you explicitly asked for a solution. Now you ask for guidance without any indication of what guidance you need. I see no sarcasm in either response - these people are trying to help you find a solution to your problem and you're being defensive / not providing te inormation they need to help you.

Comment: Okay Agreed, i will rewrite the last line of the question.

Comment: @Angelo: this won;'t be a real programming question as long as it has all of python, perl, and bash tags. If you're actually trying to solve a real programming problem, you're already working with one language. Asking for help with 3 languages means you're asking for a whole solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Does this Perl solution do what you want? You might need to adjust it:

```
perl -ane '
    @names = split /,/, $F[-1];
    print +(join "\t", @F[0 .. 2], join "\n\t\t\t", map +(split /_/)[3], @names), "\n";
'
```

**Update:**

`-n` tells Perl to proces the input line by line.

`-a` tells Perl to split each line into the array @F.

The last field is split on `,` to a new array @names. Then, the first three fields are printed, followed by the names joined by a newline and three tabs. Each name is obtained from @names by splitting it on the underscore and returning the fourth member.

### Using Text::Table to format the output:

```
perl -MText::Table -ane '
    BEGIN { $t = Text::Table->new }
    @names = split /,/, $F[-1];
    @n = map +(split /_/)[3], @names;
    my $f;
    $t->add($f++ ? (("") x 3)
                 : @F[0 .. 2], $_)
        for  @n ? @n : ("")
    }{
       print $t'
```

Comment: It works, great. Thank you. Could you please explain the script a bit. It will be very kind of you.

Comment: Thank you, but how can I fix the misalignment?

Comment: @Angelo: You can use `Text::Table` to do the formating.

Comment: @Angelo What misalignment? If it's tab separated, and some of the fields are longer than your tabsize, the table will look misaligned, but it is in fact not. This will work with the csv format. If it is only to be human readable, you should probably skip tabs and go with fixed width.

Answer (score 1):

I would consider using a script file for this, as it is a prime candidate for tweaking and reusing, and at least moderately complicated. Plus, it allows you to more easily use suitable modules for your code. [`Text::CSV`](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?Text%3a%3aCSV) will read your csv file safely, [`Text::ParseWords`](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?Text%3a%3aParseWords) will handle your nested fields.

The below script is for demonstration. You can change the file handle `*DATA` to `*ARGV` to make the script parse an argument file, e.g.:

```
perl script.pl file.csv > output.txt
```

**Code:**

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use Text::CSV;
use Text::ParseWords;

my $csv = Text::CSV->new({                     # create csv object
        sep_char => "\t",                      # delimiter is tab
    });  

while(my $row = $csv->getline(*DATA)) {        # read from file handle
    my @anno = quotewords(',', 0, $row->[-1]); # get list of fields
    @anno = "" unless @anno;                   # avoid empty list
    for (@anno) {                              # for each field
        my @inner = quotewords('[:_]', 0, $_);    # get inner fields
        my $anno = $inner[-2] // "";              # take second last
        print join "\t", @$row[0 .. 2], $anno;
        print $/;
        $_ = "" for @$row;                     # clear primary row once printed
    }
}
__DATA__
chr1    38045559    38046059    chr1:38045559-38046559_NM_001142726_C1orf122_+,chr1:38045559-38046559_NM_198446_C1orf122_+,chr1:38045952-38046952_NM_024640_YRDC_-
chr1    205291045   205291545   chr1:205290545-205291545_NM_018566_YOD1_-
chr1    1499717 1500625 chr1:1499625-1500625_NM_014188_SSU72_-
chr1    1679941 1680441 chr1:1679441-1680441_NM_001198995_NADK_-
chr1    1699769 1700657 chr1:1699269-1700269_NM_023018_NADK_-,chr1:1699657-1700657_NM_001198993_NADK_-
chr1    1701368 1701868 chr1:1700868-1701868_NM_001198994_NADK_-
chr1    1812386 1812886 chr1:1811886-1812886_NM_002074_GNB1_-
chr1    2066155 2066655 
chr1    2149493 2149993 chr1:2149493-2150493_NM_003036_SKI_+
chr1    2312573 2313353 chr1:2312353-2313353_NM_024848_MORN1_-,chr1:2312573-2313573_NM_007033_RER1_+
```

Comment: Hi! Thank you for the answer. It works well. coming to your comment of misalignment, the result file is not tab separated, that means if I want to extract the names (which is in column 4) I get few names and few blanks. How this problem can be addressed.

Comment: As I recall, you requested the first three columns printed only once. That means that unless you follow csv format when extracting the 4th col, you risk the columns being mixed up. For example, awk will by default split on whitespace, and the first 3 cols will collapse into nothing, making col 4 the only col.

Answer (score 1):

I suggest this solution, which expects the input file as a parameter on the command-line

```
use strict;
use warnings;

while (<>) {
  chomp;
  my @columns = split "\t";

  print join "\t", @columns[0, 1, 2];

  unless ($columns[3]) {
    print "\n";
    next;
  }

  my @records = split /,/, $columns[3];
  my $tabs = 1;
  for (@records) {
    my @notes = split /[_:]/;
    print "\t" x $tabs;
    print $notes[4], "\n";
    $tabs = 4;
  }
}
```

**output**

```
chr1    38045559    38046059    C1orf122
                C1orf122
                YRDC
chr1    205291045   205291545   YOD1
chr1    1499717 1500625 SSU72
chr1    1679941 1680441 NADK
chr1    1699769 1700657 NADK
                NADK
chr1    1701368 1701868 NADK
chr1    1812386 1812886 GNB1
chr1    2066155 2066655
chr1    2149493 2149993 SKI
chr1    2312573 2313353 MORN1
                RER1
```

Note that the misalignment is because of the tab-separation of the varied-length fields

**Update**

This version accumulates the output in an array and evaluates the maximum width of each column so that it can be displayed with the appropriate fixed field width

```
use strict;
use warnings;

my @output;

while (<>) {
  chomp;
  my @columns = split "\t";
  my @outrec = @columns[0,1,2];

  if ($columns[3]) {

    my @records = split /,/, $columns[3];
    for (@records) {
      my @notes = split /[_:]/;
      $outrec[3] = $notes[4];
      push @output, [ @outrec ];
      @outrec = ();
    }
  }
  else {
      push @output, \@outrec;
  }
}

my @sizes;
for (@output) {
  for my $i (0..3) {
    my $length = length($_->[$i] // '');
    $sizes[$i] = $length unless $sizes[$i] and $sizes[$i] > $length;
  }
}

for my $outrec (@output) {
  printf "%-*s %-*s %-*s %-*s\n", map { $sizes[$_], $outrec->[$_] // ''} 0..3;
}
```

**output**

```
chr1 38045559  38046059  C1orf122
                         C1orf122
                         YRDC    
chr1 205291045 205291545 YOD1    
chr1 1499717   1500625   SSU72   
chr1 1679941   1680441   NADK    
chr1 1699769   1700657   NADK    
                         NADK    
chr1 1701368   1701868   NADK    
chr1 1812386   1812886   GNB1    
chr1 2066155   2066655           
chr1 2149493   2149993   SKI     
chr1 2312573   2313353   MORN1   
                         RER1
```

Comment: Thank you for the script. Is there a way to fix this mis alignment?

Comment: It is only misaligned in the display. The fields are correctly separated by tabs, if that is what you want. Do you need this output for human consumption? I will add to my answer shortly...

Comment: Yes it is for human consumption/viewing ;)

Comment: One last thing when I am running the script, it gives me output from chr1 205291045 205291545 YOD1 instead of the first row (it just skips it)  :(

Comment: I have run my script agains the data you gave and don't get this behaviour. I can't see any way it could skip a line as it pushes a record to `@output` every time it reads a line from the input file. Haev you modified my code at all? Can you show a set of data that shows this behaviour?

Comment: Hi! I had modified your script a little bit. But I reverted back to original. One last thing, when I extract column 4 from shell using awk '{print $4}'<output>list  I do not get all the names. How can I get exact tab separation so that I have Chr in column1 and next two numeric values in column 2 and 3 and the names in column 4.  Please help. Thank you